# Intel TSX hardware transactional memory what do non-transactional threads see?

Tags: c++, c, lock-free, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

Suppose you have two threads, one creates a TSX transaction, and modifies some data structure. The other thread does no synchronization of any kind and reads the same data structure. Is the transaction atomic to it? I can't actually imagine that it can be true, since there is no way afaik to block or restart it if it tries reading a cache line modified by the transaction.

If the transaction is not atomic, then are the write ordering rules on x86 still respected? If it sees write #2, then it is guaranteed that it must be able to see the previous write #1. Does this still hold for writes that happen as part of a transaction?

I could not find answers to these questions anywhere, and I kind of doubt anyone on SO would know either, but at least when somebody finds out this is a Google friendly place to put an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(My answer is based on [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf), Chapter 12)

The transaction is atomic to the read, in that the read will cause the transaction to abort, and thus appear that it never took place.  In the transactional region, cache lines (tracked in the L1) read are considered the read-set and lines written to from the write-set.  If another processor reads from the write-set (which is your example) or writes to either the read- or write-set, then there is a data conflict.

> **Data conflicts** are detected through the cache coherence protocol.
>   Data conflicts cause transactional aborts. In the initial
>   implementation, the thread that detects the data conflict will
>   transactionally abort.

Thus the thread attempting the transaction is tracking the line and will detect the conflict when the other thread makes its read request.  It aborts and "the hardware will restart at the instruction address provided by the operation of the XBEGIN instruction".  In this chapter, there are no distinctions as to what the second processor is doing.  It does not matter whether it is attempting a transaction or performing a simple read.

To summarize, all threads (whether transactional or not) see either the full transaction or nothing.  Only the thread in a TSX transaction can see the intermediate state of memory.

Comment: That's impressive (and a well written answer, I read the same chapter before posting but did not draw those conclusions.) I wouldn't go so far as to say that other threads see the full transaction or nothing. Dirty reads (mixed old and new data) must still be possible, since some reads may have happened before the transaction began. However, if you can see a part of the transaction, then it means you can see all of it (e.g. if you re-attempted the read.) If both threads were transactional you wouldn't have this problem as either the reader or writer would abort on a dirty read.

Comment: Dirty reads are not possible (to be otherwise would break transactions).  P1, in a transaction, writes to a cache line.  P2 attempts to read that cache line.  P2 detects the conflict, aborts, and provides the pre-transaction cache line as part of cache coherence.  P2 will not provide the intermediate state.  Cache coherence is providing the serialization.  Either P2's read arrives before or after the transaction has begun.  If P1 had written to the cache line before the transaction, then there is dirty data in the cache line, but this is still the "before transaction" state.

Comment: Suppose the cache line is a list of 8 unique 64bit integers. P2 reads the first 4 integers then gets switched out. P1 runs, transactionally inserts an element into the first index and slides the other elements right by 1. P2 commits. P1 now gets switched back in and reads the remaining 4 elements (seeing the new contents) it sees the same element in index 5 as it previously saw in index 4, breaking the unique invariant of the list. Am I right that this is possible? I can't see any practical way that a processor could prevent/detect that. However, if both threads are transactions then it works.

Comment: This is possible.  I would also suggest that it is poorly designed.  There is no difference in the example if it were changed to involve a lock instead of a transaction.  TSX, transactions, locks, etc are all tools that a programmer can use to write his or her program.

Comment: Yes, well a lock where one thread takes it and one does not is only useful for serializing writers. But it's a very valuable pattern to serialize writers and not block readers under any conditions, so most of my performance critical data structures are designed that way, for better or worse.